# Is the translation/dilation of an $L^p$-multiplier again an $L^{p}$-multiplier?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Suppose that $m:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ satisfies: there exists $C > 0$ such that

$$\| (m \hat{f})^{\vee} \|_{L^{p}} \leq  C \|f\|_{L^{p}}.$$

That is, $m$ is an  $L^{p}$-multiplier. Let $M(L^{p})$  denote the space of $L^p$-[multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplier_(Fourier_analysis)).

Put $m_{\delta}(x)=  m(\delta x), (\delta >0),$ $T_{k}m(x)=m(x-k), (k\in \mathbb R).$

> My questions:

(1) If $m\in M(L^p) $, then can we say that $m_\delta, T_{k}m \in M(L^{p})$?

(2) Let $m\in M(L^p)$ and  $\phi : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$  be such that $m\circ \phi \in M(L^{p})$.  What can we say about $\phi$?

If this is known, references would be helpful.

Comment: Q1 has been answered below. For Q2 as phrase, the answer is literally nothing, since $m \equiv 0$ is a (trivial) $L^p$ multiplier.

Answer (score 3):

For $1 \leq p < \infty$, let $M( L^p(\mathbb{R}))$ be the space of all $m \in L^{\infty} (\mathbb{R})$ such that the operator 
$$ \mathcal{F}^{-1} (\hat{f} \cdot m), \quad f \in \mathcal{S} (\mathbb{R}),$$
with $\mathcal{F} : \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ denoting the Fourier transform, is bounded on $L^p (\mathbb{R})$. The norm of $m \in M (L^p (\mathbb{R}))$ is defined as 
$$ \| m \|_{M(L^p (\mathbb{R}))} = \| T_m \|_{L^p \to L^p}, $$
and one can show that $(M(L^p (\mathbb{R})), \| \cdot \|_{M(L^p (\mathbb{R})})$ forms a Banach algebra.

Regarding your question, it is stated as Proposition 2.5.14 in Grafakos' *Classical Fourier Analysis* that 
$$ \| T_k m \|_{M(L^p (\mathbb{R}))} = \| m \|_{M(L^p (\mathbb{R}))}$$
and 
$$ \| M_{\delta} m \|_{M(L^p (\mathbb{R}))} = \| m \|_{M(L^p (\mathbb{R}))}, $$
whose proof is left as an exercise. However, I think this follows immediately from the fact that $T_k$ and $M_{\delta}$ are isometric operators on $L^p$.